# sending images from java webserver to client

Tags: javascript, java, web, websocket, java-websocket

i'm new to java web App i was trying to create simple chat webapp that send images to **webserver** then the server  will send them to **other client** at first i had problem that the websocket wont send large data so i send my images using

> http request

**after encoding them to base64** then after i was able to decode it and  store it,i was trying to seend it **from** the server **to** the other client

i did not find any solution the **only  way** to send it to the other client is using websocket

this is the third day of searching and i'm thinking of given up since there is no resources for noobies

i saw alot of code but they was in high level i hope if some one have the answer of

**How can i send the image to the client ?**

please Try to explain it in a simple way

**the javascript function responsible for sending the im**g

```
send=function () {
    
               var file =document.getElementById("image").files[0];
    
    
               var content_type ={
                   headers:{
                       "content-type" : "multipart/form-data"
                   }
               };
    
                   var formdata = new FormData();
                   formdata.append('image',file);
    
                   axios.post('AddImage',formdata,content_type)
                       .then(function (response) {
                           console.log(response);
                       })
                       .catch(function (error) {
                           console.log(error);
                       });
    
           }
```

the post method that send the file

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        Part file=request.getPart("image");



        InputStream in = file.getInputStream();
        byte[] Byte_file = new byte[in.available()];
        in.read(Byte_file);



        String encodedString = "{encodedString : "+"data:image/png;base64,"+new String(Byte_file)+"}";

        //sending the String  to the  other client via his session
        socket.session.getAsyncRemote().sendText(encodedString);

    }
```

Comment: You could just send a URL to the client which would then make a request to your server to get the image.

Comment: Thank you very much, I applied the idea and it worked